# How to add padding to text in Imagemagick?

Tags: text, imagemagick, padding

I have this image 500px wide. Wanted to add some white space or padding to the text on left and right side.
I tried:

```
convert source.jpg \
        -size 500x \
        -background blue \
        -fill white \
        -pointsize 32 \
        caption:"Sed felis eros, ornare ut cursus a, imperdiet sit amet purus." \
        +swap \
        -append \
        output.jpg
```

Result:

[image]

Then tried using splice, it adds a blue column:

```
convert source.jpg \
        -size 500x \
        -background blue \
        -fill white \
        -pointsize 32 \
        caption:"Sed felis eros, ornare ut cursus a, imperdiet sit amet purus." \
        -splice 10x10 \
        +swap \
        -append \
        output.jpg
```

Result:

[image]

How to get padding around the blue text box only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [`-extent`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#extent) with a [`-gravity`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity) option? Example below (with colors to illustrate)

```
convert \( \
       -size 500x \
       -background blue \
       -fill white \
       -pointsize 32 \
       caption:"Sed felis eros, ornare ut cursus a, imperdiet sit amet purus." \
   \) \
   source.jpg \
   -append \
   -background green \
   -gravity Center \
   -extent 520x \
   output.jpg
```

[image: How to add padding to text]

Or just the text ...

```
convert \( \
        -size 480x \
        -background blue \
        -fill white \
        -pointsize 32 \
        caption:"Sed felis eros, ornare ut cursus a, imperdiet sit amet purus." \
        -gravity Center \
        -extent 500x \
    \) \
    source.jpg \
    -append \
    output.jpg
```

[image: Just the text part]

*Edit from comments*

To include top/bottom & left/right padding, then you might as well us `-border`

```
 convert -size 480x \
         -background blue \
         -fill white \
         -pointsize 32 \
         caption:"Sed feels eros, ornate ut cursus a, imperdiet sit amet purus." \
         -bordercolor green \
         -border 10x20 \
         output.png
```

[image: Top & bottom padding]

Comment: Great! Thanks emcconville . But if want to add top and bottom padding around blue box, how can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

It's easier than you think. Use something like this:

```
convert source.jpg \
        -size 500x \
        -background blue \
        -fill white \
        -pointsize 32 \
        -bordercolor blue  -border 10
        caption:"Sed felis eros, ornare ut cursus a, imperdiet sit amet purus." \
        +swap \
        -append \
        output.jpg
```

This works by adding the border with the same color as your background, so it looks like it have added the padding, but in reality this adds a border with a value of 10px in the same color. So, use it, its working perfectly.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.